# No tga textures on imported obj model

Tags: texturing, import

I downloaded this model:
https://free3d.com/3d-model/fireman-15959.html

When I import it into blender the model doesn't have the textures even if I see them in the folder.

Comment: even if I see them in the folder. do you mean you can see them in the folder ?

Comment: yes, the folder that contains the model also contains the textures